# Error: Expected spy updateRates to have been called

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I keep getting the following error: `Expected spy updateRates to have been called`, whenever I run the following test. What could be causing it? I am trying to test if the method `updateRates()` is called when I enter a value into the "From" currency field.

```
describe('App component', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [AppComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
  describe(':', () => {
    let fixture, app;

    beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      fixture.destroy();
      app = null;
    });

    it('should successfully convert GBP to GBP', fakeAsync(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        let fromAmountValueEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#fromAmountValue')).nativeElement;
        let toAmountValueEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#toAmountValue')).nativeElement;
        expect(fromAmountValueEl.value).toEqual('0');
        expect(toAmountValueEl.value).toEqual('0');

        fromAmountValueEl.value = '2';
        fromAmountValueEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
        fromAmountValueEl.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {
          'key': 'Enter'
        }));
        spyOn(app, 'updateRates').and.callThrough();
        spyOn(app, 'post').and.returnValue(new Observable<any>());

        tick();  
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(app.updateRates).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(app.toCurrency).toEqual('GBP');
        expect(fromAmountValueEl.value).toEqual('2');
        expect(toAmountValueEl.value).toEqual('2');
      });
    }));
  });
});
```

**Stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-get-post-dgcuur, not that this doesn't include the tests but should give you an indication of how everything fits together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your test like this:

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {

  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        FormsModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ]      
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should successfully convert GBP to GBP', fakeAsync(() => {
fixture.detectChanges();

let fromAmountValueEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#fromAmountValue'));
let toAmountValueEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#toAmountValue'));

tick(1000);
expect(fromAmountValueEl.nativeElement.value).toEqual('0');
expect(toAmountValueEl.nativeElement.value).toEqual('0');

component.fromAmount = 2;
fixture.detectChanges();

spyOn(component, 'updateRates').and.callThrough();
spyOn(component, 'post').and.callFake(() => {
  component.toAmount = 2;
  return new Observable<any>();
});

fromAmountValueEl.triggerEventHandler('keyup', null);
fixture.detectChanges();
tick(1000);

expect(component.updateRates).toHaveBeenCalled();
//expect(component.toCurrency).toEqual('GBP');
expect(fromAmountValueEl.nativeElement.value).toEqual('2');
expect(toAmountValueEl.nativeElement.value).toEqual('2');
 }));

it('should successfully convert GBP to EUR', fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();

let fromAmountValueEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#fromAmountValue'));
let toAmountValueEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#toAmountValue'));
component.targetCurrency = "EUR";
tick(1000);
expect(fromAmountValueEl.nativeElement.value).toEqual('0');
expect(toAmountValueEl.nativeElement.value).toEqual('0');

component.fromAmount = 2;
fixture.detectChanges();

spyOn(component, 'updateRates').and.callThrough();
spyOn(component, 'post').and.callFake(() => {
  return of({ "USD": 2.54, "EUR": 2.24 });
});

fromAmountValueEl.triggerEventHandler('keyup', null);
fixture.detectChanges();
tick(1000);

expect(component.updateRates).toHaveBeenCalled();
//expect(component.toCurrency).toEqual('GBP');
expect(fromAmountValueEl.nativeElement.value).toEqual('2');
expect(toAmountValueEl.nativeElement.value).toEqual('2.24');
```

}));
    });

[image]

Comment: Thanks, can you please let me know the eason why `expect(toAmountValueEl.nativeElement.value).toEqual('2');` doesn't work if updateRates is called? I get the error `Error: Expected 0 to equal 2.`

Comment: When I test it on the stackblitz at https://http-get-post-dgcuur.stackblitz.io/, it returns 2 if from/to GBP are the same.

Comment: @methuselah That's because `toAmount` does not change in the test case. You need to change `toAmount` somehow. One option is to change `toAmount` by faking the post method [You can change `toAmount` as per your test logic]. See my edited answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, one last thing, what if I wanted to actually test a change in toAmount, i.e. in a case where the target currency needed to be EUR triggered by an API response.. with the above approach it wouldn't be possible. How would I accomplish that if I fake the post method?

Comment: @methuselah I have added a test case 'should successfully convert GBP to EUR'. See my edited answer. You need to simply return fake data and set the target currency. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciate your help on this!

Answer (score 0):

The HTML elements referenced by `By.css('#<id>')` need to have an `id` of same name . For example `id="fromAmountValue"`.

Comment: They already have the same name on my local branch and it hasn't made a difference. Plus, I am getting the error message at `expect(app.updateRates).toHaveBeenCalled();` which somewhat proves that this isn't necessarily true.